# Why does it return `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` when I'm trying to connect backend with React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm a beginner in React and I'm following this tutorial https://dev.to/kmaryam27/step-by-step-react-nodejs-and-mysql-simple-full-stack-application-2018-part-5-5a8c to connect my database with React in front end and display the data. I kept getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` when running `npm start` at `localhost:3000` in express-react/backend/client/src in part 5. Here is my express-react/backend/client/src/App.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users:[]
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers = _ => {
        axios.get('/')
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.data.users);
      this.setState({users: data.data.users});
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  showUsers = user => <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {users.map(this.showUsers)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I get Welcome to Express express at `localhost:3001` when running `npm start` in /express/backend, and if I run `node server` as shown in tutorial part 3, I could see the database content in `localhost:3000`.

If I place a `debugger` above `console.log(data.data.users);`, I could see variable `data` returns this: 
[image]

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

`data.data` looks to contain a string instead of an object with the expected `users` key.

You should make sure you reply within the backend with a valid JSON (currently, it's an HTML as string).

Comment: What could possibly go wrong with it? Does it mean my backend hasn't successfully connected with React? I used `npm install axios` in express-react/backend and `bower install axios` in express-react/backend/client/src. Things seem worked fine until part 4.